# Swift 3 - Having issue mutating value of Array in Function

Tags: arrays, swift, function

I am attempting to take the last character from the string of each of the words in this array:

```
var nonsenseArray = ["bungalow", "buffalo", "indigo", "although", "Ontario", "albino", "%$&#!"]
```

and create a string with each of the characters using a for-loop within a function. I feel like I have a good answer but am getting the following error:

```
cannnot use mutating member on immutable value: "every" is a "let" constant
```

Below is my code:

```
func combineLastCharacters(array: [String]) -> String {
    var myString = ""
    var array = array
    for every in array {
        myString = "\(every.remove(at: every.index(before: 
        every.endIndex)))" + myString
}
return myString
```

I have found from other answers that by using:

```
var array = array
```

array should become mutable, so I can use the remove method on it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The string I am looking to create is "woohoo!"

Answer (score 0):

`array` may be mutable, but `every`is not and `remove(at:)` is trying to mutate it. Also, you're appending the characters at the start of the string. Try this:

```
func combineLastCharacters(array: [String]) -> String {
    var myString = ""
    for var every in array {
        myString += "\(every.remove(at: every.index(before: 
        every.endIndex)))"
    }
    return myString
}
```

or just:

```
func combineLastCharacters(array: [String]) -> String {
    return array.reduce("", { $0 + String($1.characters.last!) } )
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a compiler warning and no output when I try to print out the function. Warning is: "Variable array was never mutated: consider changing to 'let' constant". I used your suggestion of adding var before every, and that fixed the first issue.

Comment: @Cali_Ranger Regarding the compiler warning, do note that I removed the `var array = array` line when replicating your function. Regarding getting no output: what code are you using to print?

Comment: The lack of output I think was due to the compiler warning. Once I removed `var array = array`, the code worked.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change. variable `every` because it is defined as a `let` constant which can not be changed, I think you want `substring` instead of `remove`:

```
func combineLastCharacters(array: [String]) -> String {
    var myString = ""
    for every in array {
        myString = "\(every.substring(from: every.index(before: every.endIndex)))" + myString
    }
    return myString
}
```